# Unable to add model from database in asp.net web API project

Tags: mysql, asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2015

I am creating a `web API` in visual studio. I am using `MySQL` database. I have downloaded each and every package that is needed for MySQL from nuget. When I try to add a model from my database I am unable to add it. Below is the image.

[image]

When I press next button. The window is closed down and I am not redirected to the next step. Though the DB is added in the server explorer window, the model is not added.

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: Try re-installing the package and remove earlier references.

Comment: Can you please list down the packages other than `mysql.data, mysql.data.entity, mysql.web`

Comment: @AT-2017 I have re-installed the packages but still, it's not working. I must add one thing and it is when I try to add `MSSQL DB` then it works perfectly

Comment: Try using this link - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/visual-studio/en/visual-studio-making-a-connection.html

Comment: @AT-2017 The `DB` is already there in `Server Explorer`. I don't know still the model is not created